# can't access nested JSON

Tags: json

When I try to display the object using console log, I am getting undefined.  The line of code is:

```
              var inform = data.Payload;
              // If access allowed, set redirect location
              console.log(inform.token_use);
```

The data is a JSON object with the following values:

```
{
"StatusCode": 200,
"Payload": "{\"sub\":\"1234567-1234-1234-1234-123456778\",\"token_use\":\"access\",\"scope\":\"aws.cognito.signin.user.admin\",\"iss\":\"https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_99999999999\",\"exp\":1468310126,\"client_id\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxx\",\"username\":\"usernam\"}"
}
```

I wanted to check the value of token_use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var inform = JSON.parse(data.Payload);
```

You need to parson payload since its stringify

Answer (score 0):

'1234567-1234-1234-1234-123456778','token_use' => 'access');
$json_data= json_encode($data);
?>


    var data= '';

    var res =  JSON.parse(data);
   var inform = res.Payload;
   console.log(inform.token_use);